# Formula for semi circle with diameter up?

Tags: functions, circles

So I know the formula for a semi circle is

$$y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$$

However, what if I wanted to find the equation for a semi circle who's diameter is at the top of the graph?

Would this be the best solution?

$$y = r-\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$$

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. The result of what you are asking for is here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B5+-+Sqrt%5B25-x%5E2%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $r$ at the start is optional.  It just shifts the semicircle up so the bottom is tangent to the $x$ axis.  If you delete it the semicircle is below the $x$ axis.  In both cases it has the orientation you desire.  Good work.

Answer (score 0):

It also can be $y=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that I need the function to start on the x-axis.

Comment: One way to see this is that the equation for the full circle, $ \ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \ $ does not describe a single function (as it fails the "vertical line test"), but rather represents _two_ separate functions, since $ \ y = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \ , $ with the positive square-root corresponding to the curve for the "upper semi-circle" and the negative square-root, the "lower semi-circle".